# Optimize Haskell code calculating the sum of all the primes below two million

Tags: haskell, optimization, primes

Problem 10 in Project Euler. I saw some discussion there but only for C.

I used the following code to calculate:

```
print . sum . sieve $ [2..2000000] where
    sieve [] = []
    sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve (filter ((/= 0) . (`mod` x)) xs)
```

It takes ages to calculate. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to calculate it?

Comment: Also, a typo: you have `seive` instead of `sieve`.

Comment: It's possible to do it in sub-linear time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441627/how-to-optimize-this-haskell-code-summing-up-the-primes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many really fast ways of calculating prime numbers in haskell is described on the [haskellwiki page for Prime numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers). Specifically the second one seems to be good enough, so you might write it like this:

```
main = print . sum . takeWhile (< 2000000) $ primes 

primes = 2: 3: sieve (tail primes) [5,7..] 

sieve (p:ps) xs = h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, rem x p /= 0]  
  where (h,~(_:t)) = span (< p*p) xs
```

Running it we get:

```
ghc --make -O2 Euler10.hs
time ./SOAns
142913828922

real    0m1.598s
user    0m1.577s
sys 0m0.017s
```

The wiki describes why your solution is so slow, the main reason is that a sieve is set up for each number up to 2000000, when one for each prime is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You may find [this paper](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3127) and the ensuing discussion interesting. The bottom line is that your `sieve` implementation is not as efficient as the 'real' sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: bosmacs and HaskellElephant, thank you very much. It is very helpful.

Comment: Corrected; I was referencing the spelling of the original function.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest *optimized* prime sieving code I've personally seen in Haskell is in the [NumberSieves](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves) package, which includes both a traditional sieve based on mutable vectors and a form of O'Neill's sieve. Don't use the horrifyingly complex code in the `arithmoi` package—at least some of it is currently broken and randomly produces segmentation faults.